# FB.ui() method does not close automatically after the successful post

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      picture: "<?php echo $fb_pic;?>",
      description: $("#fb_message").text().replace("<br/>", "\n")
    }, function(response){
        if(response && response.post_id) {
                alert("Successfully posted on your Facebook wall"); 
                $(".inviteshare .sendingmsg").hide();
        }
    });
```

FB.ui() method does not close automatically after the successful post. How to fix it?